# Problem on Linear Regression

Tags: regression

Consider the following 2-variable linear regression where the error $e_i$ 's are
independently and identically distributed with mean 0 and variance 1;

$y_i = α + β(x_i − \bar x) + e_i , i = 1,2,...,n.$

Let $ \hatα$ and $ \hat β$ be ordinary least squares estimates of α and β respectively.
What is the correlation coefficient between $ \hatα$ and $ \hat β$?

There are options:
$1, 0, -1, 1/2$